# ggplot2 error in plotting a scatter plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I expect this kind of scatter plot.
However, whenever I tried to apply on my data, I get this.
[image]

I just used this code, and this is my data.
And I also confirmed they are numeric class.
`ggplot(selected.df, aes(x, y))`

[image]

making a right plot.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (instead of a screenshot of the data like you have). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

Those variables were not numeric.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).